# angularjs scope variable not updated outside directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, plunker

I'm learning directives and I have a scenario set up where I update a $scope value inside of my directive's controller. This works fine within the directive, however the $scope variable outside of the directive is not getting updated.

[I have created a plunk to illustrate this behavior.](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6OAQr4fqJ2G9XcPoSRk?p=preview) In the plunk you'll see that only the scope variable gets updated inside of the directive when clicking the reset button.

Note: I tried using `$scope.$apply();` as seen in another post but this does not work. It throws the apply already in progress error. I also read that this isn't a good way to do it. Could someone also mention why?

Comment: It's because you have isolated scope inside directive.

Comment: You can use a event based system: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kbg00us7/5/

Comment: @jcubic: How do i unisolate? I thought i would be to able to use the external scope because of the restrict property on the directive. Could you update the plunk?

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Thanks! I might go for events.

Comment: You have 3 types of scope inside directive normal scope, isolated scope when you use object in scope property and inherit scope when you use true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't send day value to directive like this:

```
<mydirective data-day="day"></mydirective>
```

Comment: Isn't that what the link function is for inside of the directive? Or is this a separate way of binding?

Comment: Not actually, with getToday method you will always get new instance of date.

Comment: Could you update the plunk so i can mark this answer?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/grBi7d?p=preview
Problem was there because you have put directive outside Controller element.